# Чат с SignalR | Angular 8 | ASP.NET-Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, angular, signalr

Пытаюсь повторить пример с чатом. [Как тут](https://www.codementor.io/ibrahimsuta/how-to-build-a-simple-chat-using-asp-net-core-signalr-and-angular-5-dvonj1tu8)
. Но как я понимаю у меня проблема с адресом хоста. Вот что я получаю при старте компонента.

[image: ошибка]

Я так понимаю у меня проблема с хостом. Само приложение я запускаю как одно целое через VS. Я не запускаю как отдельно клиентскую часть и апи бекенд.

Вот мой адресс приложения. http://localhost:59955/home/message

Мой код

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task Send(string name, string message)
    {
        await this.Clients.All.SendAsync("sendToAll", name, message);
    }
}
```

Start-up все что я добавлял

```
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
        }));
```

И в метод `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)`

```
 app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<Chat>("/chat");
        });
```

Теперь сторона клиента

```
 export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

 private _hubConnection: HubConnection;
 nick = '';
 message = '';
 messages: string[] = [];

 constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
this.nick = window.prompt('Your name:', 'John');

this._hubConnection = new 
HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('http:/:localhost:59955/chat').build();

this._hubConnection
  .start()
  .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

this._hubConnection.on('sendToAll', (nick: string, receivedMessage: string) 
=> {
  const text = `${nick}: ${receivedMessage}`;
  this.messages.push(text);
});
}

public sendMessage(): void {
 this._hubConnection
  .invoke('sendToAll', this.nick, this.message)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
 }
}
```

Есть еще один небольшой нюанс, есть файл launchSettings. Вот он
[image: launchSettings]

Скажите, в чем проблема, почему я не могу законектиться?

Comment: не смущает путь в [ошибке](http://prntscr.com/pievg1)?

Comment: Смущает, в том то и дело, что я удалить то не могу  код на бек енде и на клиенти, там и там это прописано согласно примеру на сайте что я скинул в начале вопроса, тогда вопрос в другом, почему там двойной путь?

Comment: у вас POST запрос идет по кривому адресу...проверьте на правильность формирование ссылки (`ajax` или ``form => action`)

Comment: `this._hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:5000/chat');` - опечатка в адресе

Comment: Я на данный момент вообще оставил вот так ...   ('/chat') по итогу получаю тот же рузультат. http://prntscr.com/pigckq

Comment: зайдите в инспекторе в `network`, найдите ваш запрос. В `general` есть `Request url`... добейтесь чтобы там была ссылка контроллера вашего

Comment: а вот мой ChatHub class он же не котроллер, а просто класс, у него даже нету адреса кроме того что указывется в стартапе.